# Set setcontenttype in action mapping?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portlet, content-type

Can anyone tell me how i can set content type to "UTF-8" using action response like resource Response?

I dont see any setContentType for actionResponse.

In Resource Mapping we can do it like

```
  resourceResponse.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

I also tried to encode the string using .

```
messageToCust=new String (messageToCust.getBytes ("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

Is there any other way i can set the content type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get HttpServletResponse from your actionResponse as follows:

```
HttpServletResponse httpResponse = PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse(actionResponse);
httpResponse.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```